# stripping tabs, newlines, and spaces from string output, but leave one space so that words are not connected

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, strip, spaces

I have a list_3, with one element, a string:

```
[['\n\n\n Headquarters or Regional Office\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMain Headquarters\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n Founders\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tThomas Lon Van\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n Founder Diversity\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tN/A\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n Year Founded\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2016\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n # of Employees\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1-10\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n Seeking Funding?\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNo \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n Funding Phase\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tN/A\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n'], ['\n\n\n Headquarters or Regional Office\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMain Headquarters\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n Founders\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMacKenzie T Stout,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n Founder Diversity\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tN/A\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n Year Founded\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2020\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n # of Employees\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1-10\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n Seeking Funding?\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tYes\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n Funding Phase\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPre-Seed\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n']]
```

I want to use regex to strip \n\t\r, from the output and return the text in an easy to read format

This is what I have tried:

```
list_33 = []
for i in list_3:
     string = ''.join(list_3)
     list_33.append(re.sub('\s+','', string))
print(list_33)
```

output:

```
['HeadquartersorRegionalOfficeMainHeadquarters', 'FoundersThomasLonVan', 'FounderDiversityN/A', 'YearFounded2016', '#ofEmployees1-10', 'SeekingFunding?No', 'FundingPhaseN/A']
```

This is almost what I need but I would like there to be one space between each word and colon after the first text block from list_3, ie:

```
['Headquarters or Regional Office: Main Headquarters', 'Founders: Thomas Lon Van', 'Founder Diversity: N/A', 'Year Founded: 2015', '# of Employees 1-10', 'Seeking Funding?: No', 'Funding Phase: N/A']
```

Any ideas of how I can incorporate both regex functions into one?

Thanks

ps. I know that I don't need to use a for loop for a list with just one element, but in the future the list will have more elements, I am trying to generalize the code structure using just one input right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can navigate through each string in the list and the use `re.sub` to replace each occurrence of more than 2 white space by a `:`

```
>>> import re
>>> lst = ['\n\n\n Headquarters or Regional Office\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMain Headquarters\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n Founders\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tThomas Lon Van\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n Founder Diversity\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tN/A\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n Year Founded\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2016\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n # of Employees\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1-10\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n Seeking Funding?\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNo \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n', '\n\n\n Funding Phase\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tN/A\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n']
>>> [re.sub(r'\s\s+', ': ', word).strip(': ') for word in lst]
['Headquarters or Regional Office: Main Headquarters', 'Founders: Thomas Lon Van', 'Founder Diversity: N/A', 'Year Founded: 2016', '# of Employees: 1-10', 'Seeking Funding?: No', 'Funding Phase: N/A']
```

Comment: Anad, thank you for your response, I am hoping to create a for loop that will work for a list with more than one entry. I have updated the list in the question, it now has two entries, each entry is itself a list, so the original list comprehension approach should work but I am unable to see how it translates to a for loop, any ideas?

Comment: @AndrewLittle1 `for i, lst in enumerate(list_3): list_3[i] = [re.sub(...) for word in lst]`

Comment: I will mark Prem's answer as correct for the regex portion of the question, but many thanks to @Barmar for helping me to format the answer